# Python: curses and the default black color

Tags: python, python-2.7, ncurses, curses

Why is this piece of python code not producing a normal `black` background color?

```
import curses

def func(stdscr):      
    c = stdscr.getkey()
curses.wrapper(func)
```

I really don't get it. I played around with many things (`color_pair`, `pair_number`, `init_pair`, etc). This is really not black.

I'm using the default ubuntu gnome-terminal. (But afaik it doesn't make a difference).

[image: curses - not black]

Comment: This seems to work for me, python 2.7.2. Maybe your curses module is out of date?

Comment: just in case, have you checked the gnome-terminal color scheme? Black may not be black, as far as it's concerned.

Comment: @Haidro curses is being shipped as a python builtin. I use `python 2.7.3`.

Comment: @goncalopp Yeah I changed it. But it didn't help.

Comment: probably dupes with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201106/ncurses-and-white-on-black/15878610#15878610

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you manually specify the colors, curses is going to respect your terminals color palette. Most terminals will use your settings from a .Xresources or .Xdefaults file (not sure about gnome-terminal)

However if you want to manually define your colors. Use curses.init_color, this doesn't work on all terminals, more info on its usage in the [python curses documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html). Do remember to reset the colors before quitting (curses.wrapper should do this for you).

```
def func(stdscr):
    if curses.can_change_color():
        # init_color(n, r, g, b)
        # n=0 is background
        curses.init_color(0, 0, 0, 0)
    c = stdscr.getkey()
```

Comment: That's incorrect because you cannot change the definition of color-pair 0 using that interface.

Answer (score 4):

In `gnome-terminal` there's a setting called `Palette`. It can be found under `Edit Profile -> Colors. This palette setting only applies to terminal applications.

Therefore the other settings (foreground / background colors) in the same dialog, are useless for applications.

Comment: under Palette there are 8 colors. The first one was gray instead of black for me. I changed it to black and it works.

Comment: This works for so many things relying on Curses.